# Loading (and executing) a lisp-file in autocad using .NET

Tags: vb.net, autocad, autocad-plugin, autolisp

I'm currently in the process of rewriting some old AutoCAD plugins from VBA to VB.NET. As it turns out, a (rather large) part of said plugin is implemented in LISP, and I've been told to leave that be. So the problem became running LISP-code in AutoCAD from .NET. Now, there are a few resources online who explain the process necessary to do so (like [this one](http://www.theswamp.org/index.php?topic=33352.0)), but all of them takes for granted that the lisp-files/functions are already loaded. The VBA-function I'm currently scratching my head trying to figure out how to convert does a `"(LOAD ""<file>"")"`, and the script is built in such a way that it auto-executes on load (it's a simple script, doesn't register functions, just runs from start to end and does it's thing).

So my question is. How can I load (and thus execute) a lisp-file in autocad from a .NET plugin?

Comment: Try `Autodesk.AutoCAD.Internal.AcadTaskDialogs.AutoLISPLoadSettings`
And `Autodesk.AutoCAD.Internal.Utils.RegisterLispCommand(string, string)`

Comment: There's something I really can't understand about your question. Does your VBA code call the lisp files??? If so, are the lisp files already loaded? If so, they will be already loaded with .NET as well. If not, does the VBA load the lisp files??? If it does, please post the VBA lines that does so.

Comment: It would be easier if I can understand what loads what in your old plugins.

Comment: @Daniel I did post it (more or less at least). The VBA script loads (and executes) the lisp-script by issuing `ThisDrawing.SendCommand("(LOAD ""<lisp-file>"")")`.

Comment: Ok...now, when you say script "auto-executes", you mean, when autocad is open? Or when a document is open? Or do you mean the lisp script executes itself when the vba calls load?

Comment: Does the vba code auto-execute?? Or it's the lisp that autoexecute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, there are two ways to `sendcommand` via .NET.

The first thing you need to understand is that `ThisDocument` doesn't exist in .NET.
`ThisDocument` is the document where the VBA code is written, but since your addin is document undependant, it stands alone and you must take the documents from the `Application` object.

You access the application with:

```
Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices.Application
```

If you want to transform it to the same Application object as in VBA, with same methods and functions

```
using Autodesk.Autocad.Interop;
using Autodesk.Autocad.Interop.Common;

AcadApplication App = (AcadApplication)Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices.Application.AcadApplication;
```

The first application has `MdiActiveDocument`, from where you can call the `Editor` and send written commands, or call the `SendStringToExecute` as said in other answer.

The `AcadApplication` has `ActiveDocument` (an AcadDocument object that behaves exactly as in VBA). 
This document will have the same `SendCommand` your VBA has, use it the same way it's done in VBA.

If you can explain better the autoexecute part, I can help with that too.

Comment: Ah, it seems I left out an important part of the question. The problem is that after the lisp-code has executed, I need to continue running .NET-code. I "solved" it though (not a pretty solution), by creating a `<LispFunction>` that acts as a callback and running `SendStringToExecute` with the string `(load <file>)\r(myCallbackFunc)`.

Comment: Though as your answer actually answers the question, I'm marking it as resolved.